# Why this code can't print characters in an array?

Tags: c

I compiled this code using gcc (tdm-1) 5.1.0 and please tell me why the output doesn't contain "hello"

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i;
    char st[20];
    printf("Enter a string ");
    scanf("%s",st);
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
{
    printf("%c",st[i]);
}

}
```

> Input:hello 
>   Output:     @  @

Comment: because of the garbage in the end

Comment: Use `"%s"` to print the entire string at once. As it is, you might be printing some unusual special characters afterwards that might cause your terminal/cmd to rewrite the line.

Comment: you're reading the string out of bounds, hence the behaviour is undefined. Perhaps `scanf` failed, perhaps ascii 13 - the carriage return - was printed and the garbage overwrote your hello.

Comment: this means that my input is stored in the array but it can't be displayed on the console due to some other random characters?

Comment: @pmg alright, my bad.

Comment: Two solutions: (1) `char st[20] = { 0 };` (2) `memset(st, 0, sizeof(st));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You print all 20 elements of the array, but if the user entered a string smaller than that not all elements would be initialized. They would be *indeterminate* and seemingly random.

Remember that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated*** byte strings. That *null-terminated* bit is important, and mean you can easily find the end of the string by checking the current character agains `'\0'` (which is the terminator character).

Or you could just use the [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) function to get the length of the string instead:

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(st);i++) { ... }
```

Or use the `"%s"` format to print the string:

```
printf("%s", st);
```

Also note that without any protection the `scanf` function will allow you give longer input than is space for in the array, so you need to protect agains that, for example by limiting the amount of characters `scanf` will read:

```
scanf("%19s",st);  // Write at most 19 character (*plus* terminator) to the string
```

---

Now for why your input doesn't seem to be printed, it's because the *indeterminate* contents of the uninitialized elements. While you're not going out of bounds of your array, you still go out of bounds of the actual string. Going out of bounds leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What's *probably* is happening is that some of the "random" indeterminate contents happens to be a carriage return `'\r'`, which moves the cursor to the start of the line and the output already written will be overwritten by the uninitialized elements in your array.

Comment: " They would be indeterminate and seemingly random. " they would to the console ?

Comment: that generic answer doesn't explain why the start of the string is not printed for the OP

Comment: yup. And that wouldn't hurt to put that in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short example as Qubit already explained:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main () {
   char str1[20];

   printf("Enter name: ");
   scanf("%s", str1);

   printf("Entered Name: %s", str1);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
char st[20];
```

`st` is a local variable & default array `st` contents are **garbage** not zero. So if you scan less than `20` characters into `st`, in that case remaining location of array `st` contains **garbage**, hence it's printing some junk data like `@ @` in case of

```
char st[20];
printf("Enter a string ");
scanf("%s",st);
for(i=0;i<20;i++) {
    printf("%c",st[i]);
}
```

& it's a bad practice as if user entered few char lets say 5 char, then your loop rotates `20` times, internally it will do more operations or consume more CPU cycle.

So if you want to print a *char array char by char*, then you should rotate a loop until `\0` char encounters, for e.g

```
for(i=0;st[i];i++) { /* this fails when \0 encounters */
    printf("%c",st[i]);
}
```

Or

as others suggested you can print char array `st` using single `printf` by using `%s` format specifier like

```
printf("%s\n",st); /*here printf starts printing from base address of st 
                    and prints until \0 */
```

Also it's better to initialize char array st while declaring itself. for e.g

```
char st[20] ="";
```